# Cakephp media view to display media from other source

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, download, media

I am able to display and download files uploaded to the server using the media view.

```
 function view($id) {
     $this->view = 'Media';
     $params = array('id' => $photo['url'], 'name' => $photo['name'], 'download' => false, 'extension' => 'png', 'path' => 'files' . DS . 'user' . DS . $user['id']);
     $this->set($params);
 }
```

But I also have an option where users can update a url(like amazon s3) of the file. Is there any way I can update the `path` `(in the above function)` to display the file.

I appreciate all your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, because either your server is serving those files, or s3 (for example) does.

So you have two options, and I'm using s3 for the example:

- either download the file from s3 to your server and serve it yourself via `Media`
- or, redirect the request to s3. For downloads you can set the `Content-Type` and `Content-Disposition` by appending `&response-content-type=application/octet-stream&response-content-disposition=attachment` to the url, but you can't change the filename like you can with `Media`